# mysql comparing 2 arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have sample sql query below:

```
    SELECT..
    FIND_IN_SET((SELECT cat_id
    FROM mydb.table_categories
    WHERE cat_name LIKE "%Pets%"),b.categories_id)
```

which display mysql error.

this sample query:

```
    (SELECT cat_id
    FROM mydb.table_categories
    WHERE cat_name LIKE "%Pets%")
```

return result of (25,260) and I want to compare that if it is found in b.categories_id which b.categories id contains (9,25,257,300)

In other words can we use find_in_set in this way?find_in_set((25,260),(9,25,257,300))?

Comment: you can refer to php manuals as to compare/merge/split/search php `arrays()`.

Comment: Beware that SQL wildcard searches such as `LIKE "%Pets%"` can be very slow. If you have a relatively small DB, it'll be fine, but it won't scale well.

Answer (score 2):

try using `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT ....
     FIND_IN_SET((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cat_id)
                  FROM   mydb.table_categories
                  WHERE cat_name LIKE "%Pets%"),b.categories_id)
FROM....
```

alternatively, you can still use `JOIN` or `IN` clause on this one. much better than using `GROUP_CONCAT`. *Can you post sample date with desired result?*